# AD: How can I modify the nTSecurityDescriptor/DACL/ACL from DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have tried with `ModifyRequest` but unfortunately I was not able to find the proper way.

I see it is very straightforward to do with `DirectoryEntry` but I must use the raw LdapConnection since it is the only way that allows authentication through client certificates.

If anyone has any solution or ideas, it would be great to discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really used `LdapConnection` as I usually use `DirectoryEntry`, however, I did write an article about how to work with security descriptor attributes, which might help you: [Active Directory: Handling NT Security Descriptor attributes](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2019/07/25/nt-security-descriptors.html)

I talked about getting the value from `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher`. However, I suspect `LdapConnnection` will give you a raw byte array, in which case the section on [Getting the value from DirectorySearcher](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2019/07/25/nt-security-descriptors.html#getting-the-value-from-directorysearcher) may help you, since that shows how to create an [`ActiveDirectorySecurity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectorysecurity) object from a byte array. For example, if you have the byte array in a variable called `byteArray`, you can do this:

```
var adSecurity = new ActiveDirectorySecurity();
adSecurity.SetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm(byteArray);
```

Then you can use `adSecurity.GetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm()` to convert it back to a byte array before writing it back to AD.